# Programmatically convert OneNote sections to XPS

Tags: xps, onenote

I need a way to programmatically convert OneNote sections files (.one) to XPS format. I know how it works for Excel and Word, but `Interop.OneNote` is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `Publish` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg649853.aspx), e.g.:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Onenote;

...

Application onApp = new Application();
string sectionid = "your section id here..."; //could also be a page or notebook id
string path = "your filepath here..."; //e.g. C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\hi.xps
onApp.Publish(sectionid, path, PublishFormat.pfXPS);
```